# Set of maximal independent subsets via a c# generator

Tags: c#, iterator, set

I want to find all subsets of a given set that are mutually exclusive and contain as many elements of the superset as possible. Where the user defines a meaning for exclusiveness:

```
bool exclusion<T>(T a, T b)
```

where at least `exclusion(a, b) == exclusion(b, a)` holds.

And `exclusion(a, b) == true` is guaranteed if `a.Equals(b) == true`

My code looks like this:

```
public static HashSet<HashSet<T>> MutuallyExclusive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> available, Func<T, T, bool> exclusion) {
    HashSet<HashSet<T>> finished = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(new HashSetEquality<T>());
    Recursion<T>(available, new HashSet<T>(), finished, exclusion);
    return finished;
}

private static void Recursion<T>(IEnumerable<T> available, HashSet<T> accepted, HashSet<HashSet<T>> finished, Func<T, T, bool> exclusion) {
    if (!available.Any())
        finished.Add(accepted);
    else
        foreach (T a in available)
            Recursion<T>(available.Where(b => !exclusion(a, b)), new HashSet<T>(accepted) { a }, finished, exclusion);
}

private class HashSetEquality<T> : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>> {
    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> x, HashSet<T> y) {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;
        return x.All(t => y.Contains(t));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(HashSet<T> obj) {
        return obj.Aggregate(0, (i, t) => i ^ t.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to turn this code into an iterator moving through the accepted values one by one?

**Edit:**

It seems I was I little unprecise in my question, sorry. I was actually searching for a Generator for deffered execution. So that every time you call it only the next accepted set is calculated

Comment: aside from any other problems calculating a hashcode by xor all the values gethashcode's is not the best approach.

Comment: @MitchWheat any suggestions how to do it better?

Comment: So, you're looking for all [maximal independent sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set)?

Comment: @svick actually yes, thanks for the correct term. I renamed the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is to yield a new set every time you call `finished.Add()` and it returns `true`.

But because of the recursion, you also need to yield all values returned from the recursive calls. You can do that by yielding all those values in a loop:

```
public static IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> MutuallyExclusive<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> available, Func<T, T, bool> exclusion)
{
    var finished = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(new HashSetEquality<T>());
    return Recursion<T>(available, new HashSet<T>(), finished, exclusion);
}

private static IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> Recursion<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> available, HashSet<T> accepted, HashSet<HashSet<T>> finished,
    Func<T, T, bool> exclusion)
{
    if (!available.Any())
    {
        if (finished.Add(accepted))
            yield return finished;
    }
    else
        foreach (T a in available)
        {
            var results = Recursion<T>(
                available.Where(b => !exclusion(a, b)),
                new HashSet<T>(accepted) { a }, finished, exclusion);

            foreach (var set in results)
                yield return set;
        }
}
```

It's probably not the most efficient solution, but it gets the job done.

Also, you might want to consider going through every subset only once. That way, you wouldn't need the `finished` set and you could directly yield all results you find.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `return finished;` you could use

```
foreach (HashSet<T> set in finished)
    yield return set;
```

And since you are making a generator (I think that's what they're called?), you need to change the signature of `MutuallyExclusive`from `HashSet<HashSet<T>>` to `IEnumerable<HashSet<T>>`. So basically `MutuallyExclusive` would look like:

```
public static IEnumerable<HashSet<T>> MutuallyExclusive<T>(this IEnumerable<T> available, Func<T, T, bool> exclusion)
{
    HashSet<HashSet<T>> finished = new HashSet<HashSet<T>>(new HashSetEquality<T>());
    Recursion<T>(available, new HashSet<T>(), finished, exclusion);
    foreach (HashSet<T> set in finished)
        yield return set;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't help anything, the first item will still be returned only after the whole set is computed.